# Apache start Error

Tags: apache

I have already set ServerName localhost:80

Why the command window still shows that:"
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::5dd8:c846:2050:7043. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message "